# MySQL Error: Duplicate Entry on indexing taxonomy structure with Search API

Tags: 7, database, search

**Problem**

*I have a search index. I use a views page with this to create a search page and results for users.*

I was forced to re-create my search index. I deleted the old one and I'm getting the following error when I attempt to index the new one after re-creating it.

(Technically I get 49 errors, one for each piece of content i'm trying to re-index)

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '632' for key 'PRIMARY'`

I only get this error if I attempt to index the hierarchy of a particular taxonomy field.

It sounds like it's trying to re-generate the ID for my set of items, but even uninstalling and re-installing the module and re-creating everything doesn't clear the error.

Any ideas about what might be causing it? Or what I should look for in MySQL as I dig through tables?

Answer (score 0):

I raised an issue in the Search API queue which then got patched. Forgot to post about it here. My bad.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2174163